# Quando se deve usar "senão" e "se não"?

Tags: gramática, diferenças

Como é que se distinguem as situações em que se usa a preposição "senão" daquelas em que é usada a expressão "se não" (conjunção condicional + advérbio)?

Exemplos:

> "**Se não** estás em casa cedo, ficas sem jantar."
>
> "Não conseguimos falar com ele **senão** depois da reunião."

Answer (score 11):

*Senão* (preposição) equivale a *do contrário*, *exceto*. 
Usando teu exemplo: *Não conseguimos falar com ele **exceto** depois da reunião.*

*Se não* equivale a *caso não*: ***Caso não*** esteja em casa cedo, ficas sem jantar.

Answer (score 6):

Só usamos `se não`, em duas palavras, quando pudermos empregar entre elas a palavra **porventura**.

Exemplos:

> **Se não** chover vou ao cinema.
>   **Se** porventura **não** chover vou ao cinema.

Empregamos `senão` em uma única palavra como sinônimo de:  **caso contrário** ou **a não ser**. Ou também como substantivo equivalente a defeito, deslize, etc.

Exemplos:

> Estudem bastante senão serão reprovados.
>   Estudem bastante caso contrário serão reprovados.
>
> Ele não diz outra coisa senão mentir.
>   Ele não diz outra coisa a não ser mentir.
>
> Em sua ficha não havia nenhum senão.
>   Em sua ficha não havia nenhum deslize.

Referência
ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. **Gramática da Língua Portuguesa.** 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009

Answer (score 5):

**`Senão`** é usado equivalendo a:

- Caso contrário:

**Ex:** Saia daí, senão vai se machucar.

- A não ser:

Ex: Não faz outra coisa senão reclamar da vida.

- Mas sim:

**Ex:** Não tive a intenção de exigir, senão pedir.

**`Se não`** expressa uma condição negativa equivalente a `caso não`.

**Ex:** Esperarei mais um pouco. Se não vier, vou embora.