# Sobre "já em pelo menos 1987"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, uso-mais-comum

Como dizer "o movimento tem seu início já em pelo menos 1987"?  O que quero dizer é que o movimento pode ter começado antes, mas certamente em 1987 ele já havia iniciado, pois tenho evidências claras disso. "Já em pelo menos"?  Sugestões?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Já em pelo menos* não me soa nada bem. Eu não separaria a preposição *em* do ano, e diria antes:

> O movimento teve seu início pelo menos já em 1987.

Encontras esta construção―*pelo menos já em* [+ data]―em quatro livros no [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pelo%20menos%20j%C3%A1%20em%22&num=20&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjrpaiEwqXgAhUBG3wKHTWbB3gQpwUIIg&biw=1366&bih=626&dpr=1). *Já em pelo menos* não se encontra em nenhum; *já pelo menos em*, que me parece marginalmente melhor que *já em pelo menos*, encontra-se em [um livro](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%C3%A1%20pelo%20menos%20em%22&num=20&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir-P6Vx6XgAhWpjFQKHYXdB50QpwUIIg&biw=1366&bih=626&dpr=1).

Observo a mesma coisa substituindo o *pelo menos* por outras locuções adverbiais: numa olhada rápida aos vinte primeiros resultados do Google Books, encontro vários *aproximadamente em* [+ data], mas nenhum *em aproximadamente* [+ data]; vários *o mais tardar em*, mas nenhum *em o mais tardar*. Parece que o ano gosta de ficar junto ao *em*.

Answer (score 3):

A frase original talvez fique melhor com vírgulas:

> O movimento tem seu início já em, pelo menos, 1987.

Outra variante é alterar a ordem dos termos:

> O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, pelo menos.

Algumas outras possibilidades (mantendo o presente histórico e sem listar diferentes ordenações):

> - O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, se não antes.
> - O movimento tem seu início, o mais tardar, em 1987.
> - O movimento já existe em 1987.
> - O movimento existe desde, no mínimo, 1987.

Comment: O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, senão antes.  "Senão antes" ou "se não antes"? :-)

Comment: @user4587 Boa pergunta. Mas creio que "senão" é melhor (que é, no mínimo, correto também, se veria pelo fato de ser [substituível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/sen%C3%A3o) por "quando não"), já que, eu diria, o "se não" exige que se tenha muita coisa implícita: "se não [tiver se iniciado em 1987, então foi] antes". O FLiP tem um bom [texto](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1316) sobre o assunto "senão / se não" e aqui temos a questão [Quando se deve usar “senão” e “se não”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/394/2764).

Comment: Eu tou com o @user4587 (admitindo que a pergunta é retórica): é *se não antes* = *se não tiver sido antes*, onde o *se* é conjunção condicional.

Comment: @Jacinto Agora fiquei na dúvida, então fiz a pergunta [“senão antes” ou “se não antes”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/5811/2764). :-)