# "senão antes" ou "se não antes"?

Tags: gramática

O caso geral "senão" vs. "se não" já foi abordado aqui: [Quando se deve usar "senão" e "se não"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/394/2764), e, dentre outras fontes, o FLiP tem um bom [texto](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/1316) sobre o assunto. Mas me parece que ainda há espaço para discussão sobre o caso específico:

> O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, *senão* antes.

versus

> O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, *se não* antes.

Eu diria que com "senão" é certamente correto, afinal ele é [substituível](https://dicionario.priberam.org/sen%C3%A3o) por "quando não", e ele também me parece preferível ao "se não"; por outro lado, este último também parece estar correto, desde que se tenha algo implícito, por exemplo:

> se não [tiver sido] antes

ou

> se não [tiver se iniciado em 1987, então foi] antes

Buscas no Google não ajudam muito: "senão antes" é menos frequente na busca geral, mas aparece em um maior número de livros (links: ["senão antes"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&biw=1515&bih=836&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&ei=8IdcXLekCoPW8QWVnbbwCQ&q=%22sen%C3%A3o+antes%22&oq=%22sen%C3%A3o+antes%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3008.3008.0.3098.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.nMwUOh6_rh8), ["se não antes"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&biw=1515&bih=836&tbs=sbd%3A1&tbm=bks&ei=QIdcXMGzIMeQ8wWEsaHgDw&q=%22se+n%C3%A3o+antes%22&oq=%22se+n%C3%A3o+antes%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6126.10122.0.10393.28.21.0.0.0.0.178.1931.14j7.21.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..17.5.465...0.0.1yKs3dnLMIw)), embora seja necessário cuidado na contagem, pois em vários casos as expressões pertencem a construções diferentes da de que tratamos aqui.

Enfim, pergunto: essa é uma questão subjetiva, quase de gosto pessoal, ou há argumentos formais a favor de uma das duas opções?

Comment: Percebi agora essa tua do "quando não". Parece-me que isso se resolve observando que há dois "quando nãos": *quando não* = *senão* = *caso contrário* = *ou* introduzindo uma consequência ("tá caladinho, senão levas no focinho"); *quando não* = *se não* = *ou mesmo* introduzindo uma alternativa ("ele é muito caladinho, se não mesmo mudo").

Comment: @Jacinto Aceitei a resposta do Artefakto, mas esse ponto de fato ainda estava me incomodando. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma dificuldade disto é que a distinção é pouco mais que uma convenção gráfica. O "se não antes" tem um verbo implícito, "se não teve antes/quando não teve antes". Mas como diz o artigo no PLiP,o *senão* introduzindo consequência pode muitas vezes (se não sempre) ser substituído por *se não* + um verbo: "tá caladinho, se não tás, levas no focinho" = "... senão levas no focinho".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correta é a com *se não*:

> O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, **se não** antes.

O assunto está talvez mais bem explicado aqui no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/as-regras-do-se-nao-e-do-senao/10379) do que no FLiP:

> **Senão**
>   1.2. Como elemento de ligação, pode ter os seguintes significados:
>   a. de outro modo, de contrário, de outra forma, quando não (na sequência de uma ordem, pedido, conselho, ameaça ou expressão de intenção¹): “Fala mais alto, senão não te oiço.”
>
> **Se não**
>   2.1. Quando o “se” é uma conjunção condicional que introduz uma oração na negativa, o verbo pode vir expresso ou estar subentendido:
>   2.1.2. Com o verbo subentendido: “Estavam lá dezenas de jovens, se não centenas.” Subentende-se aqui a mesma forma verbal da primeira oração (“estavam”).
>
> Uma regra simples para se verificar esta situação (2.1.2.): neste caso é possível introduzir a expressão “é que” entre o “se” e o “não”: “Estavam lá dezenas de jovens, se é que não estavam centenas!”

Aplicando o teste:

> O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, **se é que não** [o teve] antes.

Tem-se o mesmo resultado com o teste [da outra pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/394/2764), inserindo *porventura*. Mas nem é preciso ir por aí. Há frases ambíguas, mas esta não é o caso porque *senão* tem de introduzir a consequência de negar a frase anterior. Um exemplo com *senão* poderia ser:

> O movimento decide ter seu início já em 1987, **senão** poderia tornar-se tarde demais.

---

<sub>¹ Encontram-se muitos exemplos em que não se vislumbra «ordem, pedido, conselho, ameaça ou expressão de intenção».</sub>

Comment: "ordem, pedido, conselho, ameaça, expressão de intenção" não deve ser exaustivo? "O movimento tem seu início já em 1987, senão não teríamos estes folhetos impressos já em janeiro de 1988"?

Comment: @Jacinto sim, parece-me que essa restrição não tem sentido de ser. Procurando no CETEMPúblico, há muitos exemplos de troca de _se não_ por _senão_, mas nos que encaixam na regra não se encontram frequentemente esses elementos: _Enquanto isso não acontecer, adiantou ao PÚBLICO o vereador Mota Alves, os trabalhos não podem iniciar-se, senão são considerados ilegais_, _é um fenómeno de invasão internacional, senão teríamos feito uma exposição nacional e não internacional_. Vou pôr uma nota.